# How to add a fixed navbar to your app

Tags: css, css-position

Similar to what you see here: http://jsfiddle.net/U8HGz/493/show/

I've tried `{position: fixed}` in css to no avail. It seems like my bootstrap is pretty darn stubborn!

#### Part of my CSS file

```
@import "bootstrap";


.navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top { position: absolute!important;
    position: fixed;
    }
```

Comment: Looks OK to me, what's the problem/expected result?

Comment: @sachleen I didn't expect this from you! :P

Comment: Dude, your class declaration is wrong. Please check my answer.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I'm really confused, haha. The nav bar is fixed to the top of the page.

Comment: @sachleen Check his selector buddy...

Comment: @PraveenKumar I saw that it's wrong after reading your answer, but I couldn't figure out the problem from the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what your latest code looks like now but try updating it to either of these:

Set left and right properties to 0:

```
.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-static-top {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

or you could give your rule a width:

```
.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-static-top {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

See an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/uberrobert/s7u8K/

Comment: Uberroberts solution is the proper one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Dude you didn't specify the value for `top` or `bottom`. Remove the `position: absolute;` too.

And your class declaration is wrong, replace:

```
.navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top
```

With:

```
.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-static-top
```

You should not give spaces.

Do this:

```
.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-static-top {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: That worked sort of dude, it's now 'fixed' but it's bunched up on the left as opposed to being a full bar across the top.

Comment: Update, removing the spaces with '.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-static-top' has given it the fixed functionality which is great, but now it has also changed the appearance of the Nav. The nav is no longer a vertical bar across the top of the page. Can we have a vertical navbar across the top, and have it fixed?

Comment: Like what? Can you give us a fiddle or screenshot?

Comment: Dude, can you use imgur.com? I cannot access that...

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/TNdJS3V.png this one is now fixed which is great but it looks weird

Comment: and how it used to look - http://i.imgur.com/wDcuEpm.png

Answer (score 0):

Fixed positioning combined to absolute positioning WITH !IMPORTANT will obviously lead to absolute positioning being applied over fixed. Choose one of them (and no need to add this [`!important`](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/))

```
### Updated
@import "bootstrap";


.navbar .navbar-inverse .navbar-static-top {
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. Praveen is closest but with his way the nav is no longer one horizontal bar across the top it's sort of bunched up on the upper left. It is now 'fixed' as it scrolls nicely, but need it to be a horizontal bar across.